# GtkAboutDialog not working when press two times

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, glade

I am starting GtkAboutDialog from a menubar item. This is the function toggling the dialog:

```py
def open_about(self, *args):
        x = about.run()
        if x == -4:
            # When pressing close;
            about.destroy()
```

If I click the menubar about item once, there is no problem, dialog opens and I can close it as you would expect. But if I click again, an empty window appears. It's only available once.

```
(translate.py:31837): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 19:44:24.373: gtk_widget_show: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

(translate.py:31837): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 19:44:24.373: gtk_label_set_markup: assertion 'GTK_IS_LABEL (label)' failed

(translate.py:31837): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 19:44:24.376: gtk_container_foreach: assertion 'GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Destroying the about window to close it caused it to be available only once.

```
about.destroy()
```

I should've hided it instead:

```
about.hide()
```